# JSF Upload component: alternate triggering

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I have a JSF form that needs to upload a file via an icon click (i.e. without showing the textfield/browse button of the file upload component).

Is it possible to trigger the file-open dialog and uploading functionality of the upload component via some other component type?

Answer (score 0):

No, the file upload dialog is meant to be pretty much unchangeable as a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any other "off the shelf" component you could use to trigger the file-open dialog (which, after all, results from a `<input type=file>` written by the renderer).

However, if you're willing to develop your own renderer, it could write both the `<input>` and your icon's `<img>` (one right after the other). Give the `<input>` a css class that uses absolute positioning to place it on top of the `<img>` and reduces it's opacity to 0 (you could also set the cursor to 'pointer').

Now, when the user clicks on the *icon*, they're also clicking on the invisible input, which pops up your dialog.

(Now that I think of it, I'm almost positive you can do this without writing your own renderer by just applying the same kind of css to off the shelf components...)

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5, there is new way to styling the css with bootstrap for example and replace image by a glyphicon.

```css
.btn-file {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
  width:32px;
  font-size:24pt;
  height:12px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"> </span> <input type="file">
      </span>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is the input file intended to cover the whole area?